# Как сделать редирект если действие кода было соблюдено в javascript?

Tags: javascript, odnoklassniki-api

Привет всем 
данный пример кода проверяет если человек опубликовал или нет пост в соч сеть одноклассники 
если он опубликовал то возвращает alert если нет то ничего не возвращает
Как поставить чтобы возвращало redirect на другой адрес если он поделился  а  alert если он не поделился ?
Вот код

```
            <script>
                !function (d, id, did, st) {
                  var js = d.createElement("script");
                  js.src = "<? echo $klass22; ?>";
                  js.onload = js.onreadystatechange = function () {
                  if (!this.readyState || this.readyState == "loaded" || this.readyState == "complete") {
                    if (!this.executed) {
                      this.executed = true;
                      setTimeout(function () {
                        OK.CONNECT.insertShareWidget(id,did,st);
                      }, 0);
                    }
                  }};
                  d.documentElement.appendChild(js);
                }(document,"ok_shareWidget","http://site.ru/t/load.php?id=<? echo $create_id;?>","{width:125,height:50,st:'straight',sz:45,ck:1,nc:1}");

                function listenForShare() {
                    if (window.addEventListener) {
                        window.addEventListener('message', onShare, false);
                    } else {
                        window.attachEvent('onmessage', onShare);
                    }
                }
                function onShare(e) {
                    var args = e.data.split("$");
                    if (args[0] == "ok_shared") {
                        alert(args[1]); // Вывод идентификатора фрейма кнопки - в случае нескольких кнопок на одной странице, по нему можно определить какая именно была кликнута
                        if (alert)
                        $( '#baner_grup' ).show();

                        $( '.classs' ).html('<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=http://example.ru/hh.php" />');

                        $( '#class' ).hide();
                        $( '.player' ).hide();


                    }
                }
                listenForShare();
```

Comment: не уверен, нету возможности протестировать, возможно что то на подобии 
if(typeof e === 'undefined')
сработает?

Comment: незнаю а как по другому

Comment: Ну у вас же есть возможность попробовать прямо сейчас, как вариант испытайте.

Comment: не работает  if(typeof e === 'undefined')

Comment: а если console.log(e) что выдает?

Comment: ничего просто ничего , может поставить проверку , если человек опубликовал ему выводит alert и проверить если он нажымает ОК то будет редирект , как это сделать ?

Comment: это не alert это prompt

Comment: как поставить вместо alert , prompt

Comment: извиняюсь нужен confirm
var isconfirm = confirm("Перейти на страницу odnoklasniki.ru");
if(isconfirm){//do some} else {//do some}

Comment: как это интегрировать в код ?

Comment: alert(args[1]); // Вывод идентификатора фрейма кнопки - в случае нескольких кнопок на одной странице, по нему можно определить какая именно была кликнута if (alert); у вас есть этот кусок кода замените alert на сonfirm, таким способом вы сможете отследить нажал пользователь ok или no